# Bootstrap 3.1.0 dynamic added buttons has no margins

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm having some trouble with dynamically added bootstrap buttons. The appended buttons don't get any margins.

I was able to recreate this by going to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons and re-ordering the buttons with chrome dev tools (F12 in chrome).

[image: Original layout]

Image below shows layout after I moved one of the buttons
[image: Layout after reordering]

I'm wondering what is causing the original nice layout and can I trigger a re-layout in some way?

Comment: Check with dev tool which style is not apply and deduce why

Comment: I could not find, in dev tools, why the buttons are spaced as they are (values for display and margin is the same). Also should not the css be the same when i re-order elements? The re-ordering destroys the layout.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. If i reorder buttons, same style is applied, keeping accurate margin

Comment: @gSpotTornado : Please share the HTML with your buttons, and the JS where you add the new button.

Comment: I recreated the issue at http://jsfiddle.net/dYYqY/1/. Screen shot for comparison http://i.imgur.com/VqrsJlP.jpg